# Android Emulator shows only on a small part of the screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a problem with my android emulator. It only shows a fraction of the screen.

Screenshot:

[image: Problem]

I have Android Studio version 3.0.

I tried a lot of things. I could fix the error when I use the emulator with Software emulated graphics but it is really slow.

know someone the solution?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have configured [hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html?utm_source=android-studio) correctly.**

1. Disable the Device Frame by edit action.

   [image: avd edit]
2. Start the emulator and Go to Extended Control

   [image: extended]
3. Go to Settings and change OpenGLES render to **Desktop native OpenGL**

   [image]
4. Restart Emulator and Resize the Emulator Window.

   [image]